# How do I use a perspective projection matrix?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I wrote this program, but I want the square to change size as it moves further away.

```
package com.ncom.src;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.*;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Main {
    public void start() {
        float y = 0;
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 500000000, -500000000);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex3f(350, 250, y);
                glVertex3f(350, 270, y);
                glVertex3f(370, 270, y);
                glVertex3f(370, 250, y);
            glEnd();
            Display.update();
            y -= 20;
        }

        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Main quadExample = new Main();
        quadExample.start();
    }
 }
```

Comment: No I don't care about the maths, it is just everywhere I look there is no actual code. How to I program a square to be drawn at depth or 'not on the screen' in perspective?

Comment: @Dr_N: Well, by understanding the math. Programming is the process of turning mathematical notation into programming language source code. Learning from "code examples" won't teach you the interesting part. Especially for graphics, where a single, short line of mathematical notation may expand into a screen full of code.

Comment: @datenwolf: Can you give me any place to start learning? I really have no idea where to look

Comment: @Dr_N: First there's Nicol Bolas set of tutorials: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut which also cover some of the math. I strongly recommend getting an undergraduate textbook on linear algebra. When I was TA-ing I did recommend the book "Mathematics for 3D Game Programming & Computer Graphics" by Eric Lengyel, Charles River Media. As for online resources, there's some worth material on the math at http://www.lighthouse3d.com/ – in addition to that many of the advanced topics are published online by various research groups (e.g alice.loria.fr) and also game studios (Valve software publishes a lot).

Comment: @Dr_N: When you read some reasearch paper also always follow the references. It's like digging a gold mine that only  gets richer. Note that the book I refered to is not about linear algebra. I recommend that as supplementary material. For linear algebra head into the undergraduate mathematics section, far away from computer science literature!

Comment: I while back (+ 10 yrs) I wrote some computer graphics code for displaying flight dynamics and also robotics.  The code did visual tracing hidden lines, perspective, and line of sight reflections.  I was following a book, and the book gave a good description of the math.  Unfortunately, I can't remember the name of the book. But I believe it had to do with 3d rendering.  I know that's not much of a lead.  But another lead, if you look into history, the company SGI specialized in high performance graphic systems, and they had a lot of notes on usages / application.

Comment: I notice your age is listed as 14, so you might have to get acquainted with matrices and vectors. You only need basic algebra, and there are plenty of easy introductions via keyword search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code `glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 500000000, -500000000);` is for an orthographic view, try using GLU.gluPerspective(). Example:

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluPerspective(field_of_vision, Display.getWidth()/Display.getHeight(), zNear, zFar);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see a perspective, then I'd start by using a perspective projection.

```
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        near = 1; // near should be chosen as far into the scene as possible
        far  = 100;
        fov  = 1; // 1 gives you a 90° field of view. It's tan(fov_angle)/2.
        glFrustum(-aspect*near*fov, aspect*near*fov, -fov, fov, near, far);
```

Comment: For those who are wondering about this, [here's a link to NeHe's Productions that provides the math logic behind gluPerspective()](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/replacement_for_gluperspective/21002/). It's very useful for those who likes to learn via scratch.